# Is it possible to order records by value that is calculated from column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, sql-order-by

I have table `Project` with column `ProjectRegNumber`. From this column it is possible to get year (f.e. if column value is 855589/14 year is 2014 (20 + last two numbers). I have method `GetYearFromRcn` for this (parameter reg. number, return value year). I am showing all projects in `GridView` where one column is year - this is working fine.

But now I want to get records ordered by a year (calculated from column `ProjectRegNumber`). Is this possible or do I have to add another column with year value to my table?

My method for getting data without ordering looks like this:

```
public static List<Project> GetProjects()
{
 using (var ctx = new NSMASEntities())
 {
  return ctx.Project
   .ToList();
 }
}
```

Here i want to add something like `.OrderBy(project => GetYearFromRcn(project.ProjectRegNumber))`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: That look perfectly valid using Linq.

Comment: I think he is going to use CLR method `GetYearFromRcn` which can't be converted to linq expression

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: It could be made more readable by making `GetYearFromRcn` an extension method for `Project` then it would become `return ctx.Project.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.GetYearFromRcn()).ToList();`

Comment: When I add this OrderBy clause (in my post) it ends up in following error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetYearFromRcn(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq will not be able to convert your `GetYearFromRcn` method to linq expression.

You need either to execute it first.

```
return ctx.Project
          .ToList()
          .OrderBy(p => GetYearFromRcn(p.ProjectRegNumber))
          .ToList();
```

Or use [**DbFunctions.Right**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.right%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) like this.

```
return ctx.Project
          .OrderBy(p => "20" + DbFunctions.Right("00" + p.ProjectRegNumber, 2))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Apologies, I had overlooked the requirement to execute the entity retrieval before ordering.